# Modify existing endorsement policy (Hyperledger Fabric)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I had 2 organization in Hyperledger Fabric blockchain network initially. Recently I added one more organization on a different host using swarm. When I try to invoke chaincode from 1st or 2nd organization then it's working fine and I can see the updated transaction from org3. But when I invoke a transaction from org3, I am getting the following error.

> "[2019-02-06 06:44:21.895] [ERROR] invoke - The transaction was
>   invalid, code = ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE"

Initially, chaincode was initiated using the following policy.
 -P "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"

So I think I will have to update existing endorsement policy to include org3.

Could anyone help to modify existing endorsement policy or to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to upgrade the chaincode is as followed:

- Increment the version of ccRequest containing ccPackage
- Re-Install the ccRequest on all orgs in the channel.

  Ex: `peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 2.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/`
- Create new ccPolicy with correct rules containing required orgs as endorsers.
- Upgrade the chaincode by running upgradeCC command

  Ex: `peer chaincode upgrade -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -v 2.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","90","b","210"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer','Org3MSP.peer')"`

  - Test with a query on chaincode with `peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'`

For more details refer [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/channel_update_tutorial.html#upgrade-and-invoke-chaincode) or ask on [rockerchat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using **peer chaincode upgrade command**.

> peer chaincode upgrade -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile
>   $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n mycc -v 1.2 -c
>   '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200","c","300"]}' -P "AND
>   ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer','Org3MSP.peer')"

refer : [peer chaincode upgrade](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/commands/peerchaincode.html?highlight=upgrade#peer-chaincode-upgrade-example)